# What is the point of the median?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

It seems like the purpose of the median is to ignore a specific type of data point. More specifically, it is used to make outliers have a lower weight than other data points on an average.

Why not just remove the data point (i.e. the outliers) and calculate the mean? This way, the outlier has 0 weight on the average. Or use a weighted average where the outliers are assigned weights close to 0?

Am I right in saying that the median is inferior to other algorithms?

Comment: An obvious 'point' is to have the value $m$ such that $P(X > m) = 1/2$.

Comment: The median is also used to make half of the students feel better in a specific class. As you can see, this is a primarily opinion-based question.

Comment: How do you propose to identify 'outliers' in an algorithmic fashion?  You're correct that there are still other ways of doing weighted averaging and weighted fitting, but it's very hard to have a cleanly defined 'weighted average' of a set of points where the weight of the individual points is defined using the result of the weighting algorithm!

Comment: Furthermore, 'Am I right in saying that the median is inferior to other algorithms?' - given the sheer volume of uses to which the median is put, the answer here is a pretty clear no.  If the median were obviously inferior, it would hardly see as much use as it does.

Comment: My general experience has been that, *very frequently*, one talks about averages is not because it is what you actually want to know, but simply because it is something you can compute with, and so we struggle to try and take advantage of what we can compute to tell us something.

Comment: @user117273 : who decides which data points are outliers, or how many outliers there should be?  What criteria do you use?  These questions far from obvious.  The median is easy to compute and often does a good job of de-empshasizing outliers.  Whether it is inferior to other algorithms in describe "typical" data problem depends on your application and the data sets you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outliers do not have a 'lower weight than other data points' in a median. This is a bad way of looking at the median, which is based on trying to interpret it as some kind of mean.

If you remove any value below the median from the distribution, the median goes up by the same amount, regardless of whether it's an outlier or not. Similar if you remove a point above the median. Thus all points to one side or other of the median arguably have the same 'importance' to the median.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The median can be used in places where the mean cannot. For example, rank scales, where the difference between the numbers are not well-defined (eg the effort put in for a gold medal in the Olympics could be very near that of the silver, but largely different from the bronze)

The median is an alternative form of central tendency. When a population has many different extreme values and we wish for a single decent representative value of a population, the median should naturally be favored over the mean.